Orthographic Projection and Concentric Circles
Let $C$ be the bounded set of concentric circles centered at the origin.
Let $r_n = \sqrt{\frac{n}{\pi}}$ for any integer $n \in [1, k]$ be the radius of the circle $C_n \in C$.

Assume $C$ is a hemisphere of the orthographic projection of the sphere $S$.
Let $C'$ be $C$ that's projected back onto $S$.
Let $D_n$ be the distance from $C_n'$ to $C_{n+1}'$.
Is $D_n = D_{n+1} \; \forall n$?

Are you asking if the parallels (lines of constant latitude) are equally spaced on the sphere if we assume that their projections onto the equatorial plane are spaced as you've described?

@SammyBlack. Is $C$ equivalent to the lines of constant latitude, when orthographically projected back to $S$? If so, then yes.

Those are certainly lines of constant latitude, whether their latitudes are equally spaced or not.

We will derive the radius of the circles of equally spaced latitude under orthographic projection along the polar axis of the unit sphere.
Since by construction, consecutive equally spaced circles of latitude subtend the same angle measure $\phi$ from the sphere's center as measured along a line of constant longitude, it follows that if we use a regular spacing corresponding to angles
$$\left\{ \frac{k \pi}{n} \right\}_{k = 1}^{n-1}$$
as measured along a line of constant longitude, with $0$ being the "north" pole and $\pi$ being the "south" pole, this yields $n-1$ equally spaced circles on the sphere with separation $\phi = \pi/n$.  Then the orthographic projection of these circles will yield circles with radii
$$r_k = \sin \frac{k\pi}{n}, \quad k \in \{1, 2, \ldots, n-1 \}. \tag{1}$$  These of course do not coincide with the definition given in the question
$$r_k = \sqrt{\frac{k}{\pi}}, \quad k \ge 1, \tag{2}$$
since in the case of $(2)$, the sequence is unbounded above, thus cannot correspond to equally spaced circles of latitude for any sphere of finite radius.  Indeed, any truncated subsequence, say
$$\left\{\sqrt{\frac{k}{\pi}}\right\}_{k = 1}^n$$
would have as maximum radius $\sqrt{n/\pi}$, which would require a sphere with radius $R \ge \sqrt{n/\pi}$.  If we regularized this sequence, say
$$\sqrt{\frac{k}{\pi}}\left/\sqrt{\frac{n}{\pi}}\right. = \sqrt{\frac{k}{n}}, \quad k \in \{1, 2, \ldots, n\} \tag{3}$$
this would just give you concentric circles with radii $\sqrt{1/n}, \sqrt{2/n}, \ldots, 1$.
What would be the difference in latitudes for consecutive circles in $(3)$ as a function of $k$?  It would simply be
$$\arcsin \sqrt{\frac{k+1}{n}} - \arcsin \sqrt{\frac{k}{n}}, \quad k \in \{1, 2, \ldots, n-1\}.$$

Ah! That was the word I was looking for "bounded." I thought "finite" was synonymous. Thank you for the answer, but I'll wait for others first. I'll edit the question in the mean time.

The answer is obviously no in the general case.
Consider the case $n = 90$. Then the circle with radius $\sqrt{\dfrac1\pi}$ is the projection of the line of latitude at $89$ degrees latitude (one degree from the pole) and the circle with radius $\sqrt{\dfrac2\pi}$ is the projection of the line of latitude at $88$ degrees latitude (two degrees from the pole).
Within two degrees of the pole, the curvature of the sphere doesn't amount to very much. Distances on the hemisphere in this region are approximately the same (at least to within a couple of digits of accuracy) as the distances between the orthographic projections of the same point.
So the line of $88$ degrees latitude should project to a circle with about twice the radius as the projection of the line of $89$ degrees latitude. But instead, you have a circle with a radius only $\sqrt2$ times as large. So these cannot be the projections of the $88$th and $89$th parallels.
Alternatively, consider the case $n = 3$.
Then the circle with radius $\sqrt{\dfrac1\pi}$ is the projection of the line of latitude at $60$ degrees latitude and the circle with radius $\sqrt{\dfrac3\pi}$ is the projection of the equator.
The radius of the line of latitude at $60$ degrees is half the radius of the hemisphere, so its projection also should be half the radius.
In other words, the equator should project onto a circle exactly twice the radius of the projection of the line of latitude of $60$ degrees. But its radius is only $\sqrt3$ times as large.
The only cases that work appear to be $n = 1$ and $n = 2$.
